# I am having some problems with C++ file

Tags: c++

I need help with this code. It is a Bakery Management System and I am having issues with adding the products to the file(a txt file)every time I add a product it just shows the name of the product and the rest it's just weird symbols and not recognizable by the system which also affects the buy() function.

```
  class addProduct{
    char name[100];
    Date product_date, validity;

    public:
        float price, discount, total;
        int number, quantity, day, month, year;
        Date sales_date;
        void add();
        int disc();
        
};

ofstream file;
addProduct product;
addProduct quant;

void addProduct::add(){
            cout<<"Please enter the product name: ";
            cin.ignore();
            cin.getline(name, 100);
            cout<<"Please enter the product number: ";
            cin>>number;
            cout<<"Please enter the product quantity: ";
            cin>>quantity;
            cout<<"Please enter the price: ";
            cin>>price;
            cout<<"Please enter the discount(%): ";
            cin>>discount;
            cout<<"Please enter the product date(day, month, year): ";
            product_date.enter();
            cout<<"Please enter the validity(day, month, year): ";
            validity.enter();
}

int addProduct::disc(){
    discount = (price*discount)/100;
    total = price - discount;
    return total;
}

void add_product(){
    ofstream file;
    file.open("BakeSale2.txt", ios::app);
    product.add();
    file.write((char*)&product,sizeof(addProduct));
    file.close();
}
```

[The output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZ4Gw.jpg)

Comment: Ivanna, if you want to write to a text file, you cannot simply typecast the object to a character string. That will not do any good, unless you implement some casting operator, see for example https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator
You probably just want to write it item by item, formatted in the way you wish in the output text file...

Answer (score 0):

you can not simply cast your class to a char* in this line:

file.write((char*)&product,sizeof(addProduct));

i recommend you use the possibility of overloading the output operator(<<)

```
ostream &operator<< (ostream &ostr, const addProduct &p)
{
   ostr << p.price << endl;
   ostr << p.number << endl;
   ostr << p.quantity << endl;
   //etc ...
   return ostr;
}
```

in the public section of your class addProduct you then have to declare the overloaded operator as a friend like:

```
friend ostream &operator<< (ostream &ostr, const addProduct &a);
```

if u have done that u should be able to use the operator like:

```
file << product;
```

Comment: Thank you so much, but how should I put it?

Answer (score 0):

You should properly format your output. file.write does not work with proprietary types like this. right now, it just dumps the memory of the object.

You could do something like:

```
file.write("name: ");
file.write(product.name);
file.write('\n');
file.write("price: ");
file.write(product.price);
etc...
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I'm going to try that

Comment: I've tried it but it shows an error:  69 23 C:\Users\IvannaShipp\Desktop\C++ Pogramming\BakeSaleMockUp.cpp [Error] no matching function for call to 'std::basic_ofstream<char>::write(const char [7])'